# AngularJS changes defined header when sending request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am running an angularjs app and I am having trouble finding out why my $http call changing my request header.

I define the header I want as `'accept': 'application/JSON'`. But when I look at the request header I see `Accept:  */*`

My code is:

```js
.controller('StopDetailCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.info = fetch();

  function fetch(){
        var uriBuilder = 'http://api.translink.ca/rttiapi/v1/stops/55612?apikey=u8RWYB3HmxjsHenpDk0u'

    $http({
          method: 'JSONP',
          url: uriBuilder,
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/JSON'
          }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          console.log('Success', JSON.stringify(response));
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log('Error', JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    }
})
```

The uri does return a value but it is XML which causes an error to be thrown.
The error I keep getting back is a json string:

```
    {
  "status": 404,
  "config": {
    "method": "JSONP",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "url": "http:\/\/api.translink.ca\/rttiapi\/v1\/stops\/55612?apikey=Y3pJJjLVyfPetMoowJP4",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application\/json, text\/plain, *\/*"
    }
  },
  "statusText": "error"
}
```

The network dev console tells me the Request Headers are:

```
Referer:    http://localhost:8100/?restart=125748
Accept: */*
Cache-Control:  max-age=0
```

`Accept:    */*` is different than the header I put `headers: {'Accept': 'application/JSON'}`

The api I am using is: https://developer.translink.ca/ServicesRtti/ApiReference

Comment: Replace your header with   headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json' //standard header syntax
          } ..and try.  and May be some CORS issues involved

Comment: It was a CORS issue. :-C